# replace ids of html elements in jquery clone object

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have some HTML that I would like to be cloned several times and appended to the document. It's just typical HTML form stuff. But since things like `<label for="something">` works based on element IDs, it would be nice if each HTML element within the jquery `clone()`'d element could have a unique ID, apart from all their cloned counterparts. Just as a guess to how I could do this, I wonder if it would be possible to make the IDs within my initial element all contain some unique string. I could then somehow traverse the element and replace that string with a _1,_2,_3 etc.

I haven't gotten very far, but it seems like something like this should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var toReplace = "containerUniqueCharacterString1234";
  var copy = $('#containerUniqueCharacterString1234').clone(true);

  copy[0].style.display = "block"; //so i can reference the first element like this

  console.log(copy[0]); //[object HTMLDivElement] 

  $('body').append(copy);

  $.each(copy, function(index, value){

    var children = copy[index].childNodes;
    console.log(children); //[object NodeList] 

    var len = children.length;

    if (copy[index].childNodes.length > 0){
      if (copy[index].childNodes.hasOwnProperty('id')){

        //replace the toReplace string with an incremented number here(?)
        //annnnd this is where i've gotten in too deep and made this overly complex

       }
    }

    $('#otherResults').append(len);

  });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ecojub/1/edit

Or perhaps there's a much much simpler way to do this.
Thanks!

Comment: You can wrap a label around the input element as well. Mileage may vary :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better for you to use classes inside the clone?

Comment: @popnoodles probably. but as I explained, something require specific IDs. So for me, it's a must. Thanks

Comment: "something require specific IDs" so you can't use this selector: "`#element1 .someinput`" "`#element2 .someinput`" "`element3 .someinput`" to specifically target things? You're using jQuery - it's probably not a must.

Comment: I bet if you gave more info about why you think you need this we can probably tell you why you don't. It IS possible to do what you want. I very much doubt it's necessary.

Comment: @popnoodles sorry typo. _some things_ require specific IDs. The only way I know to (through just HTML) tick a checkbox when it's label is clicked is by matching up `for=` and `id=`. http://jsbin.com/afowen/1/edit

Comment: oh just put your label around the checkbox `<label>this is the label for check 2
  <input type="checkbox">  </label>`

Comment: @popnoodles As you like, I think I'm going for the template suggestion, but changing properties of Jquery objects would be, if not useful, at least interesting to know how to do.

Comment: @popnoodles that's cool. no idea there was such an easy fix thanks. though i'm still interested in the other thing.

Comment: yes templates are very useful. I use mustache.

Answer (score 1):

If you are copying HTML elements many times for display only, maybe you should consider using a templating engine rather than copying the DOM elements, which are expensive and less maintainable. underscore has a pretty easy to use function, http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template

Comment: okay. 4kb. very cool. Though I am still just sort of interested in how to traverse a jquery object and change specific attributes, I will definitely check this out. Thanks!

Comment: What you are thinking is probably a versatile function that can go into certain DOM elements recursively and modify the child elements. Here is an example that I added to your jsbin page, http://jsbin.com/ecojub/6/edit